# Angularjs with using Salesforce Ajax Toolkit

Tags: apex, visualforce, angular

I am trying to write a VF page using Angularjs with salesforce Ajax Toolkit. However I am continuously greeted with following error.

{Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://na15.salesforce.com/toDoHome.htm. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).}

So few questions are arising in my mind
1) is it possible to use angularjs with salesforce ajax toolkit.
2) If yes , am I missing out on anything?
3) Or should I be using Ajax proxy?

{

```
        function getTasksR(callback){
              result = sforce.connection.query("Select Id from Task", callback);
        }


        var app = angular.module('todo', ['ngRoute'])
        app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
            $routeProvider.
            when('/', {
                 templateUrl : '/toDoHome.htm',
                 controller : 'todoCtrl'}
                ).
            when('/new', {
                templateUrl : '/newTask.htm',
                controller : 'newTaskCtrl'}
                ).
            otherwise(
                {redirectTo : '/'}
            );
        }]);

        app.controller('todoCtrl', function($scope, $location){
              $scope.getTasks = function() {
                getTasksR(function(){  
                    $scope.$apply(function(){  
                        onSuccess: success;
                        onFailure: failure;


                    });   
                });
              }

              function success(result){
                $scope.taskData  = result.getArray("records");
                alert($scope.taskData);
                $scope.apply();
              }

              function failure(error){
                alert(error);
              }
              $scope.getTasks();

        });
    </script>}
```

Comment: Have you added you current domain to [CORS List](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/01/spring-15-preview-cors-force-com-rest-api.html).  SETUP>  Security Controls > CORS. I think your current domain will be something like `https://c.na5.visual.force.com`

Comment: Hi @manjit_singh, I have already tried adding different combination for urls but it did not help.